# Documents created on a MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, xserver

I have a Xserver running MongoDB and several computers have access to the DataBase, I want to know how can I know which computer create each document.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solution:

1.If you using mongodb [ObjectId](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification) and because of object id contains information about machine where it was created

> Machine. This is the first three bytes of the (md5) hash of the
>   machine host name, or of the mac/network address, or the virtual
>   machine id.

You can parse objectId of document and get information about machine from these three bytes.

2.Another solution is two save information about machine in each document.

Comment: Thanks Andrew but all the machine host name are the same, I guess because all the operation are taking place on the server and not on each machine. I was thinking on your second solution but I´m working with a system that was created by another company and I think I´m not allowed to make changes to their code.